Importance of the 2004 exponent in 2004 AIME II Problem 8
The 2004 AIME II Problem 8 is as follows

How many positive integer divisors of $2004^{2004}$ are divisible by exactly 2004 positive integers?

The relevant parts of the solution for my question are

The prime factorization of 2004 is $2^2\cdot 3\cdot 167$. Thus the prime factorization of $2004^{2004}$ is $2^{4008}\cdot 3^{2004}\cdot 167^{2004}$.
...
A positive integer divisor of $2004^{2004}$ will be of the form $2^a\cdot 3^b\cdot 167^c$. Thus we need to find how many $(a,b,c)$ satisfy
$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 167$$

My question is, what is the importance of the exponent of $2004$? Would this argument work for any integer exponent? It looks like you would write out $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 167$ and get the same solution no matter the exponent.

Note that every year, the question writers try to have a problem that involves the year number itself. I don't think there's anything else special here.

@SeanRoberson I picked up on that, but I still didn't know if there still needs to be some sort of property the exponent needs to satisfy. Like would it still work with an exponent of $1$? Does the exponent need to be large enough?

No. You can show this works for any integer.

They want the number to be big enough that a solver won't be tempted to just list all the divisors and check each one.  So not $2004^1$ or $2004^2$, say.

@RobertIsrael I suppose, although if the exponent doesn't matter then you could still do that?

It's also significant that 2004 has several prime factors.  If you were looking for divisors of $2017^{2017}$, for example, the problem would be much easier because 2017 is prime.

Not sure I understand your point. Of course the exponent matters, it gives you bounds on $(a,b,c)$.  For instance, $2^{2003}$ is a possible answer.

@lulu Well... that's the whole point of my question. I don't see how the value of the exponent determines any part of the solution

As I say, $2^{2003}$ is an answer to the given question, but it wouldn't be an answer if  the exponent were lower.

@lulu So then where does the value of the exponent come into play in the solution? From the solution outline in the link, I don't see where it comes into play

I mean, you need $2^a3^b167^c$ to divide your original number.  That test will, of course, depend on what the original number is.

@lulu I am following the logic. That is why I am making my post here..... I don't see where that reasoning comes into play in the linked solution. Based on how the solution is put together, it looks like you would write out $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 167$ no matter the exponent

You are ignoring the divisibility.  You need $a≤4008$, $b≤2004$, $c≤2004$.  If the exponent were, say, $1$ instead of $2004$, those inequalities would be $a≤2$, $b≤1$, $c≤1$.

@lulu Ok.... so then the answer would be different for different exponents? Why can't someone post an answer? Conflicting replies in the comments here

I'll post, just for completeness.

The exponent matters because we require that $2^a\times 3^b\times 167^c$ divides $2004^{2004}$.  That tells us that $$a≤4008\quad \quad b≤2004\quad \quad c≤2004$$
If the exponent was, say, $1$ instead, those inequalities would read $$a≤2\quad \quad b≤1\quad \quad c≤1$$
in particular, $167^{2003}$ is a solution to the given problem, but it certainly wouldn't be a solution if the exponent were $1$ (or any number smaller than $2003$ for that matter).  Of course, with exponent $1$, there would be no solutions at all.
Perhaps worth noting that it wouldn't matter if the exponent were higher.  If you switched to $2005$ or more,  the answer is unchanged (why?). For that matter,  the answer is unchanged if you had exponent $2003$ but not lower.

Ok, so the unspoken part of the solution is that the exponent needs to be at least as large as the number of required integers that the divisors are divisible by? If it was smaller the solution would need to adjust?

It was spoken!  The problem asks you to count divisors of the original number.  So you need $(a,b,c)$ to be such that $2^a\times 3^b\times 167^c$ actually is a divisor.
